# What are the possible targets of tooltip in ReactStrap other than id?

Tags: css, reactjs, user-interface, tooltip

```
<div>
  <p>Somewhere in here is a <span style={{textDecoration: "underline", color:"blue"}} 
        href="#" id="TooltipExample">tooltip</span>.</p>
  <Tooltip placement="right" isOpen={tooltipOpen} target="TooltipExample" toggle={toggle}>
       Hello world!
  </Tooltip>
</div>
```

This tooltip targets the span having id "TooltipExample". What are other possible targets than id. I am using BootstrapTable of react and it doesn't support id attribute.

I want tooltip on below code.

```
<TableHeaderColumn dataField="associateName" dataSort={true} id="TooltipExample">
                   Name
</TableHeaderColumn>
```

but id is not working because TableHeaderColumn doesn't have any id attribute I guess.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/tooltips/), the target can also be a `DOMElement` (which can be obtained from [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) in React):

```
Tooltip.propTypes = {
  ...
  target:  PropTypes.oneOfType([
    PropTypes.string,
    PropTypes.func,
    DOMElement, // instanceof Element (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)
  ]).isRequired,
  ...
}
```

Example:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const ref = React.createRef();

  return (
    <>
      <div ref={ref}>This will trigger a tooltip</div>
      <UncontrolledTooltip
        placement='top'
        target={ref}>
        I'm a tooltip!
      </UncontrolledTooltip>
    </>
  );
};
```

Looks like there's a [bug](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/1472) with ref targets in v8 of Reactstrap though, so you might have to use an earlier version until that is fixed.

Alternatively, couldn't you add a wrapper element around `TableHeaderColumn` with an id and target that instead?